# What should I look for when buying a UV protection window film

Tags: protection, uv-exposure

I'm searching for a window film for UV protection but there's just so many choices online with large price variances.

All films I had a look at claim to protect against 99% UV so I'm not really sure why some films are more expensive than others.

What should I be looking for when choosing a UV protection film? Any good brands you would recommend?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic. Some may be easier to install and higher quality or thicker film. Whatever you decide really look into how to clean and prep the windows, 1 spec of dust can make an otherwise nice job look bad.

Comment: Unless you're doing this to reduce head load from UV-B, I wouldn't bother.  The health risks of spending rather little time in direct sunlight thru windows is pretty small.

Comment: Unless one suffers from albinism.